# Clojure shell/sh does not handle single-quoted arguments correctly?

Tags: bash, shell, clojure, ffmpeg

Executing the following command in the REPL:

```
(shell/sh "ls" "-lah" "'resources'")
```

gives the following output:

```
{:exit 2, :out "", :err "ls: cannot access 'resources': No such file or directory\n"}
```

Executing the same command in the Bash shell gives the correct output, the list of files in the resources directory. To my understanding this means that shell/sh is unable to handle single-quoted arguments correctly. Is this true or am I doing something wrong?

The example above is a simple example, as usually I probably would not need to single-quote the folder name. But why this is a real problem is because I try to concat audio files by executing the following ffmpeg command using shell/sh;

```
ffmpeg -i resources/ffmpeg_working/1.flac
-i resources/ffmpeg_working/2.flac
-i resources/ffmpeg_working/3.flac
-i resources/ffmpeg_working/4.flac
-filter_complex '[0:0][1:0][2:0][3:0]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1[out]'
-map '[out]'
resources/ffmpeg_working/done.flac
```

This gives the following output

```
Stream map ''[out]'' matches no streams.
```

Once again, if I execute the same ffmpeg command in the Bash shell it concatenates the files successfully. Thus, it seems that the single-quoted argument is not handle correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting is a shell feature, to avoid shell expansion of what would otherwise be interpreted as wildcards, variables, etc. When you are using something other than the shell, eg clojure/java process-management tools, there is no such thing as wildcards or variables, and thus no such thing as quoting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, does it mean that it is completely impossible to execute shell commands that *require* single-quoted arguments?

Comment: You have misunderstood the answer completely. You are not executing a shell command at all, you are running a program as if by [`EXEC(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec). You "can't" quote things, because there is no need to quote anything ever.

Comment: According to this page https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate "the single quotes around the whole filter section are required." and this is why I need to quote them.

Comment: Actually, you're quite right. I removed all single quotes when executing ffmpeg commands from Clojure and it to works fine. No need to quote anything, ever :)

Answer (score 4):

As @amalloy mentioned, you should not be using single quotes around `resources`.  Compare with & without:

```
(require '[clojure.java.shell :as shell])
;=> nil
(shell/sh "ls" "-lah" "'resources'")
;=> {:exit 2, :out "", :err "ls: cannot access 'resources': No such file or directory\n"}
(shell/sh "ls" "-lah" "resources")
;=> {:exit 0, :out "total 8.0K\ndrwxrwxr-x 2 alan alan 4.0K Nov  4  2015 .\ndrwxrwxr-x 8 alan alan 4.0K Jul 14 10:25 ..\n", :err ""}
```

Please note that you are not running any shell at all; you are talking straight to the unix kernel, so wildcard expansion doesn't occur. For example, the following command looks for a file named `*` (star), there is no shell to interpret the `*` character as a code that means "any matching file":

```
(shell/sh "ls" "-l" "*")
;=> {:exit 2, :out "", :err "ls: cannot access *: No such file or directory\n"}
```

If you wish to have your command interpreted by the shell before being passed to the Linux kernel, you may wish to use the `shell-cmd` function [in the Tupelo library](http://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.misc.html#var-shell-cmd):

```
(require '[tupelo.misc :as tm])
nil
clj.core=> (tm/shell-cmd "ls -l *")
{:exit 0, :out "-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 11218 Nov  4  2015 LICENSE\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan    16 Jul 12 17:59 my-file.txt\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan   520 Jan 25 08:29 project.clj\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan   457 Nov  4  2015 README.md\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan  4975 Nov  4  2015 tmp.txt\n\ncheckouts:\ntotal 0\nlrwxrwxrwx 1 alan alan 17 Dec  7  2015 tupelo -> /home/alan/tupelo\n\ndoc:\ntotal 4\n-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 101 Nov  4  2015 intro.md\n\nresources:\ntotal 0\n\nsrc:\ntotal 4\ndrwxrwxr-x 2 alan alan 4096 Feb  4 16:28 clj\n\ntarget:\ntotal 4\ndrwxrwxr-x 4 alan alan 4096 Jul 14 10:25 base+system+user+dev\n\ntest:\ntotal 4\ndrwxrwxr-x 3 alan alan 4096 Dec  7  2015 tst\n", :err ""}
```

Note that `shell-cmd` accepts only a single string argument that is passed straight to the shell, not multiple arguments like `clojure.java.shell/sh`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want shell features, you can call your shell directly. Bash supports `-c` to run some command in a normal bash context. This is useful when you need setup from `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

```
(require '[clojure.java.shell :as shell])

(defn bash [command]
  (shell/sh "bash" "-c"
            command))

(bash "ls -lah 'resources'")
;; => {:exit 0, :out "lots of text", :err ""}
```

You can use any shell feature now. Example with pipes:

```
(bash "find . | grep .clj")
;; => {:exit 0, :out "./src/user.clj\n", :err ""}
```

Your shell is just an application that can launch other applications. You can tell a shell to launch an application. When you launch an application with clojure.java.shell/sh, you're not doing it *on top of bash*, but in the same way that bash launches its applications.

Advantages by not indirecting via bash:

- You have better control on input. Escaping input if you want to pass it to bash is difficult.
- You are purposefully not depending on configuration from the shell. This information is often very different from system to system, and may cause you problems in production.